# Google Glass Proxy Configuration

Tags: proxy, google-glass

Is there anyway to either configure a systemwide proxy on glass itself or a proxy setting only for my own application while its running on the glass?

Comment: Can you describe in more detail what you are trying to accomplish our what your use case is?

Comment: Sure thing. I am trying to connect my glass to internet through a proxy server. Something easily configured on a regular android device. Is there either a way to set a proxy for the system or perhaps only for a specific application that I am writing.

Comment: why not simply use the existing bluetooth to phone or "secure" wi-fi registered access (i.e. what is there already)?

Comment: Well phone is not an option. There is also no way to set proxy settings (at least what I have found) when setting up a WiFi connection